# Compact sets in geodesic metric space

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, compactness

Are compact sets in a geodesic metric space necessarily bounded? What about, if the space is proper?

Comment: What do you mean "proper"?

Comment: @rschwieb usually a proper metric space or sometimes a heine-borel metric space is a metric space in which every closed ball is compact.

Comment: @JacobSchlather Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Compact sets in *any* metric space are bounded. This is easily seen by taking any point of the set and covering the space with the union of open balls of radius $n$ centered on that point.